# Problem displaying request headers with apache httpclient 4

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I've been trying to retrieve the headers sent by a HttpMethod, using HttpClient 4, but without any  success...

here is my code :

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.google.fr");

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

log.info("*** Request headers ***");
Header[] requestHeaders = httpGet.getAllHeaders();
for(Header header : requestHeaders) {
    log.info(header.toString());
}
log.info("***********************");


log.info("*** reponse ***");
log.info(response.getStatusLine());
Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
for(Header header : headers) {
    log.info(header.toString());
}
```

but the result is :

```
00:27:57,368 INFO   - *** Request headers ***

00:27:57,368 INFO   - ***********************

00:27:57,368 INFO   - *** reponse ***

00:27:57,368 INFO   - HTTP/1.1 200 OK

00:27:57,368 INFO   - Date: Sun, 15 Aug 2010 22:28:09 GMT

00:27:57,368 INFO   - Expires: -1

00:27:57,368 INFO   - Cache-Control: private, max-age=0

00:27:57,368 INFO   - Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

00:27:57,368 INFO   - Set-Cookie: 

[..]
```

Aka the response headers are good, but not the request's. ( Same result if I move the log request headers block before the execute statement ).

(and NO, I dont want to simply see them, so setting the log level to debug isnt acceptable )

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only display the request headers you've set yourself.

If you want to log the request headers which HttpClient has set, then you need to configure HttpClient's builtin logging by [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/). Also see [this document](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/logging.html).

As an alternative, you can also use an external tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I said changing the log level isnt acceptable : I need to store the sent headers. You sure there is no way to get them, before or even after executing the request ?

Comment: While this answer is perfect okay, I think solving the problem without logging is a better solution (see the most upvoted answer). <sub>(I didn't vote this answer.)</sub>

Answer (score 12):

To get all headers including those which the HTTPclient sets, use
HttpCoreContext. This class allows to read out all the headers.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpCoreContext localContext = new HttpCoreContext();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request,localContext);

Header[] headers = localContext.getRequest().getAllHeaders();
for (Header header : headers) {
   System.out.println(header.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Things may have changed since 2010, however this can be done by using a request interceptor (to inspect the request at a lower level) with amazingly similar code.

```
// So we can get all the headers (not just the ones we explicitly set).        
httpClient.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {

    public void process(
            final HttpRequest request,
            final HttpContext context) 
            throws HttpException, IOException {

        // Start Debug
        System.out.println("*** Request headers ***");
        Header[] requestHeaders = request.getAllHeaders();
        for(Header header : requestHeaders) {
            System.out.println(header.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("***********************");
        // End Debug
    }

});
```

In my case, I get the following output (having only explicitly set two of these).

```
*** Request headers ***
Accept: application/xml
Authorization: Basic bmV3Omd1ZXN0
Content-Length: 772
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Host: rest3api.sifassociation.org:80
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 (java 1.5)
***********************
```

May this help those who travel here.